# VBA Excel 365 macro from Add-in not visible in new workbook after Alt-F8

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a set of Subs in VBA and saved them as .XLAM

I added this .XLAM to the add-ins via options

All macros are allowed (during the tests)

When opening a new workbook I see the add-in macros in the Developer->Visual Basic

When I enter Alt-F8 to get an overview of the available macros the list is empty

What am I doing wrong?

[image: xlam file]
[image: Add-ins overview]
[image: Empty macro list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro (Sub) doesn't appear in the `Macro` window (Alt+F8), but you can add a command button on Ribbon that links to the macro.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Short follow-up question. How can I now address the Thisworkbook of the "host" workbook?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook which hold the code. `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook object which shows in Excel window.